# Domande sull'uso dei tempi verbali in una frase

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

A: "Sbagliai apposta quella domanda."

B: "Certo, non mi è passato per la testa neanche per un secondo che tu *abbia potuto* sbagliare."

Ho un dubbio su quell'*abbia potuto*. Forse avrei dovuto usare *avresti/avesti/avessi*? O quale altro tempo? Qual è la regola in questo caso?

Comment: Non capisco perché questa domanda sia tanto difficile di rispondere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Che tu ____ sbagliare" è una proposizione subordinata completiva oggettiva retta da un'espressione di tipo dubitativo ("passare per la testa") che [regge il congiuntivo](http://paduaresearch.cab.unipd.it/4276/1/tesi_dottorato.pdf). Dunque, il condizionale non è possibile.

Secondo Maria Cristina Peccianti, *Grammatica italiana per stranieri* (Giunti Editori, 2013):

> Quando la proposizione subordinata richiede il verbo al modo congiuntivo, se nella proposizione reggente c'è un tempo passato, si seguono queste regole:
>
> - Per esprimere **contemporaneità**, si usa l'**imperfetto**: *Non mi è passato per la testa che tu potessi sbagliare* (come @DaG ha spiegato, se B ha sentito dire che A aveva sbagliato e si è detto: "Non è possibile!").
> - Per esprimere **anteriorità**, si usa il **trapassato**: *Non mi è passato per la testa che tu avessi potuto sbagliare* (se l'azione di B pensando è posteriore allo sbaglio di A).

Answer (score 0):

In questo caso si usa `avresti`, quindi il tempo verbale condizionale, e non congiuntivo come hai usato tu.

Infatti per la concordanza dei tempi (http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordanza_dei_tempi) la frase principale è al passato (`è passato`) e rispetto al momento in cui si compie l'azione descritta dal verbo passare, `poter sbagliare` è posteriore.

Comment: «rispetto al momento in cui si compie l'azione descritta dal verbo passare, poter sbagliare è posteriore»: non è detto. È possibile che B abbia sentito dire che A aveva sbagliato e si sia detto: «Non è possibile».

Comment: Infatti lo sbaglio , o la possibilità di sbagliare che dir si voglia, è riferito a un tempo passato. Quindi, secondo il link fornito, dovrebbe essere "che tu avessi potuto sbagliare", no?

Comment: Io sono madrelingua italiano, e in questi casi ho sempre usato il condizionale.. Quindi avresti

Comment: Anche io sono un madrelingua italiano, e quella che mi suona meglio è *abbia potuto*, ma, almeno alla luce delle regole della concordanza, la forma giusta dovrebbe essere *avessi potuto* perché anche A usa *sbagliai* e non *sbaglierò*, sottolineando l'anteriorità. Cercavo soltanto una conferma perché l'orecchio non mi aiuta e di grammatica sono a digiuno.